# Half Hexagon Hover Effect

Tags: jquery, css, svg, css-shapes

Here I have a small example:

**HTML:**

```
<section>
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="hex1">
      <div class="hex2" style="background: url('http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mb3lh6abw91rg4gq5o1_500.jpg') center no-repeat">
        <div class="desc">
          <h2>Normale Seite</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/hex2-->
    </div>
    <!--/hex1-->
  </div>
  <!--/hexagon-->
</section>
```

**CSS: (SCSS)**

```
@import "compass/css3";

/* Variables */
$width: 300px;
$pink: rgba(230,0,98,.75);
$green: rgba(169,160,50,.75);
$yellow: rgba(252,171,55,.75);
$brown: rgba(83,70,54,.75);

body {
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 960px;
}

.hexagon {
  @include rotate(120deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: ($width *2);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: $width;
}

.hex1 {
  @include rotate(120deg);
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}


.hex2 {
  @include rotate(120deg);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}

.desc {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: ($width * 2);
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  visibility: visible;
  width: $width;
  &.base {
    background: $pink;
  }
  &.one {
    background: $yellow;
  }
  &.two {
    background: $green;
  }
  &.three {
    background: $brown;
  }
  h2 {
    margin: ($width - ($width / 4)) 20px 0 20px;
  }
}
```

**JS: (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var color = 'one';
  var counter = 0;
  $('.desc').hide();
  $('.hexagon').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).find('.desc').fadeIn('fast');
      counter++;
      if (counter === 0) {
        color = 'base';
      } else if (counter === 1) {
        color = 'one';
      } else if (counter === 2) {
        color = 'two';
      } else if (counter === 3) {
        color = 'three';
      } else if (counter >= 4){
        counter = 0 ;
        color = 'base';
      }
      $(this).find('.desc').addClass(color);
    }, 
    function() {
      $(this).find('.desc').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).removeClass(color);
      });
    });
});
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Kampfschaf/pen/oXooYg)

I don't find a way to cut the hexagon in two parts.

I am stuck now. I want a half hexagon, a trapezoid with hover effect. The form is this hexagon. The cut must be between bottom left to top right. I want another text in the center when I hover the top left hexagon and another when hover the bottom right part of the hexagon.

Like [this Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6shnt.jpg):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You should always add the code into the question itself. Demo links are good but you should not bypass the quality check by formatting links as code blocks. I have also added the image into the question.

Comment: ALLRIGHT! Next time ;-) THX

Comment: CSS isn't the best tool for abstract geometry. You should try using SVG instead.

Answer (score 5):

This sort of shape will be extremely difficult within CSS. Your best alternative would be to use SVG which is much easier to build, use and style for such geometrical shapes.

All you will need to do is change up the colours and also the positioning for the text.

```css
.top {
  fill: red;
}
.top:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
.bottom {
  fill: orange;
}
.bottom:hover {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 116">
  <polygon points="2,31 52,2 98,29 89,34 52,13 11,36 11,79 2,84" class="top"></polygon>
  <polygon points="6,91 15,86 53,107 93,84 93,40 102,35 102,89 53,116" class="bottom"></polygon>
  <text x="40" y="60">test</text>
</svg>
```

- [SVG | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG)